# É permitido usar sprites gratuitos da Unity asset store em jogos monetizados?

Tags: unity3d, unity-5

É permitido usar sprites gratuitos da Unity asset store em jogos monetizados?
Vi que na Unity Asset Store tem muitos sprites que são gratuitos. Estava pensando em começar a desenvolver alguns jogos simples para Android e publicá-los na PlayStore. Isso é permitido? Posso usar eles eles, por exemplo, para criar jogos gratuitos que possuam propaganda ou até mesmo em jogos onde é possível fazer compras de itens sem nenhuma restrição?

Answer (score 4):

Boa tarde Vinicius, existem muitos assets livres para monetização. Os que tem a marcação CC0 (public domain) significam que você usar os assets para fins comerciais. Eu trabalho com jogos aqui no brasil e frequentemente disponibilizo assets para fins CC0 (public domain) gratuitamente. Se tiver interesse pode me enviar seu email que entrarei em contato :)
Espero ter ajudado, abraços.

Comment: Todo asset que esteja registrado em alguma creative commons que não contenha -NC (_non commercial_) você pode monetizar. Até mesmo CC-BY-ND

Comment: É verdade Jefferson! Obrigada por completar a resposta :) Porém a mais comum nessa plataforma do unity asset (quando é livre) é a CC0.